# Show that $P$, an $n \times n$ matrix, is a projection given only that $P^2 = P$, and $P^T = P$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

> Let $P$ be a $n \times n$ matrix such that $P^2 = P$ and $P^T = P$. Show  that $P$ is the projection onto a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$. *Hint: If P is indeed a projection, the subspace P is projecting onto must  be ??. Show that $\overrightarrow{b} - P\overrightarrow{b}$ is orthogonal to ??.*

**Question**: According to the professor, showing that all vectors in the column space of $P$ being orthogonal to $\overrightarrow{b} - P\overrightarrow{b}$ is enough to show that P is a projection. Why is this true? And how do I show it?

**Steps I've Taken**: I've tried constructing a matrix $A$ such that it's column space forms a basis for a subspace onto which $P$ supposedly projects, but I can't find how to leap from that fact to proving orthogonality. Also, I don't believe this is the right approach, since it isn't using the column space of $P$.

Comment: What is your definition of projection? For me it is a linear map such that $\;P^2=P\;$ , but for you obviously must be something different.

Comment: A projection is a matrix P such that when you multiply it with a vector, you get a "projection" of the original vector on the subspace. For example, projecting a vector in three dimensions onto a plane. We haven't discussed "mappings" or used that terminology in our class, we've only discussed matrices, subspaces, etc

Comment: You are using the defined word (projection) in the definition. I don't think that makes much sense.

Comment: We use the terminology in class similar to the one used here: im not good enough at this to explain it further https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06sc-linear-algebra-fall-2011/least-squares-determinants-and-eigenvalues/projections-onto-subspaces/MIT18_06SCF11_Ses2.2sum.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwippq74vI7LAhVFqB4KHabuCr4QFggjMAE&usg=AFQjCNELsHvZgV0AcuL2iwfy-QfbxrA58Q&sig2=Kd0OIpB5yhVl5O-r_Vg1TQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not well clear, but I'm attempting an answer.

First note that the usual definition is that

> a linear transformation $P$ is a projector if $P^2=P$

Your additional condition $P^T=P$ caracterize the **orthogonal** projectors (in a **real** vector space $V$), where:

> $P$ is orthogonal if the kernel of $P$ is orthogonal to its range.

Now note that for any vector $y \in V$ we have that $(y-Py)$ is an element of $\ker(P)$ because $P(y-Py)=Py -P^2y=0$.

So, $P$ is an orthogonal projector if $\forall x,y \in V$ we have :
$$
\langle Px,(y-Py) \rangle=0
$$
But this is done because:
$$
\langle Px,(y-Py) \rangle=\langle P^2x,(y-Py) \rangle=\langle Px,P^T(y-Py) \rangle=\langle Px,(Py-P^2y) \rangle=\langle Px,0 \rangle=0
$$

Answer (score 0):

I think the computation you are asked to do (taking into account $P^T=P$ and $P^2=P$) is as follows. The dot product of $Pb-b$ and $Pb$ is $0$, as proven by the following computation:

$$(Pb-b)^T(Pb)=((Pb)^T-b^T)(Pb)=(b^TP^T-b^T)(Pb)$$

$$=(b^TP-b^T)(Pb)=b^TP^2b-b^TPb=b^TPb-b^TPb=0$$.

I add a drawing:

[image: Geometric view of a projector]

Going further:

$P^2-P=0$ can be expressed as: "$P$ verifies $f(P)=0 \ \ (1)$" where $f$ is the polynomial defined by $f(X)=X^2-X$.

If you aquainted with the theory of *minimal polynomials*, it means that $f(X)$ is the minimal polynomial of $P$ (otherwise, we should take a first degree polynomial, and it won't do: a relationship $aP+bI=0$ would entail that $P$ is a multiple of the identity matrix). Thus, as the characteristic polynomial is a multiple of the minimal polynomial, the roots of $X^2-X$, i.e., $0$ and $1$, will both be roots of the characteristic polynomial, and thus eigenvalues of $P$.

The eigenspace associated with eigenvalue 1 is the subspace you are going to project on: in fact, writing $Pu=u$, means that vector $u$ has already been projected, and a supplementary projection let it indifferent...

The eigenspace associated with eigenvalue 0 is the subspace you are going to project "parallel to". This subspace is evidently the kernel of $P$ (the simplest case being when this subspace is 1D). Moreover, as $P$ is symmetric, all the eigenvectors associated with different eigenvalues will be orthogonal; thus $P$ will be an orthogonal projection.